# What is best way to access variables from different python modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python scripts, one which processes data and other which creates an HTML report reflecting the processed data.

test1.py:

```
def test(self):
    for i in data:
        if data is this:
            data[1] = something
        if data is that:
            data[1] = something
        else:
            data[1] = something else
```

test2.py:

```
OutFile = open("C:/path/../result.html", "w")

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\"
# want to print data[1] value here
```

What is the best way to pass the value in `data[1]` from `test1.py` to `test2.py`? Can I pass using arguments to `test2.py`?

Comment: Call a function in `test2.py` and pass it. Why do you have `self` as an argument to `test()` when you never use it?

Comment: Does test2 need to be a separate script? It would be easy for `test1` to import `test2` as a module, then run some function in it with the desired data.

Comment: How are you planning to run these? Do you want `test1` to run `test2`? Or for the shell, or some other program, or you manually, to run both of them independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return it from the function:

```
class MyClass():
    data = some_data
    def test(self):
        for i in data:
            if data is this:
                data[1] = something
            if data is that:
                data[1] = something
            else:
                data[1] = something else
            return data
```

And in `test2.py`, grab and put it somewhere:

```
from test1 import MyClass
my_instance = MyClass()
data = my_instance.test()
print(data[1])
```

**Alternative 1**

Put it as a variable in `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass():
    data = some_data
    def test(self):
        for i in self.data:
            if self.data is this:
                self.data[1] = something
            if data is that:
                self.data[1] = something
            else:
                self.data[1] = something else
```

And in the `test2.py`, take it as a property of `my_instance`:

```
from test1 import MyClass
my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.test()
print(my_instance.data[1])
```

**Alternative 2**

If you want to run both scripts independently, you can make `test1` put the data somewhere accessible by `test2`. For example, in a file:

```
class MyClass():
        data = some_data
        def test(self):
            for i in data:
                if data is this:
                    data[1] = something
                if data is that:
                    data[1] = something
                else:
                    data[1] = something else
            with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.writelines(data)
```

Now, you can easily have it from your second script:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print (data[1])
```

It's not that difficult to achieve this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoters, if something is wrong with my code, please give me an advice on how to fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the python `pickle` package:

```
import pickle
#in py1
pickle.dump(data, open(some_dir + "data.pkl","wb"))
#in py2
data = pickle.load(open(some_dir + "data.pkl","rb"))
```

Although I am not sure how big your lists are; this will be slow for huge lists. If its just a few values though, the overhead will be nonexistent.

Comment: this should not have been downvoted. The answer above suggested "putting the data in a file". That's exactly what I am doing, only the way its meant to be done via pickle.

Comment: Me neither. Well, no worries, serial downvoters usually get handled pretty quickly. I'll fix yours.